# Using auto and decltype in templated functions

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, auto

I've been trying to use auto return type templates and am having trouble. I want to create a function that accepts an STL map and returns a reference to an index in the map. What am I missing from this code to make it compile correctly?

(Note: I'm assuming the map can be initialized with an integer assignment of 0. I will likely add a boost concept check later to ensure it's used correctly.)

```
template <typename MapType>
// The next line causes the error: "expected initializer"
auto FindOrInitialize(GroupNumber_t Group, int SymbolRate, int FecRate, MapType Map) -> MapType::mapped_type&
{
    CollectionKey Key(Group, SymbolRate, FecRate);
    auto It = Map.find(Key);
    if(It == Map.end())
        Map[Key] = 0;
    return Map[Key];
}
```

An example of code that calls this function would be:

```
auto Entry = FindOrInitialize(Group, SymbolRate, FecRate, StreamBursts);
Entry++;
```

Comment: What compile error are you getting? Also, there's no need to use `decltype` here or late-specified return types; just put it on the left as normal.

Comment: Do you really mean "STL"? Or do you mean "C++03 standard library"? Or, given the tag, "C++11 standard library"? Pick one please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `typename` before MapType in the suffix return type declaration.

If you forget to add the `typename` you would get such kind of error (here GCC 4.6.0) :

```
test.cpp:2:28: error: expected type-specifier
test.cpp:2:28: error: expected initializer
```

That would give you something like :

```
template <typename MapType>
auto FindOrInitialize() -> MapType::mapped_type&
{
    ...
}
```

But for what you are trying to do, there's no need for suffix syntax :

```
template <typename MapType>
typename MapType::mapped_type& FindOrInitialize() 
{
    ...
}
```

Here if you forget the `typename` you get an error like :

```
test.cpp:2:1: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘MapType::mapped_type’ because ‘MapType’ is a dependent scope
```

Which is much more explicit!

Comment: Thanks Geoffroy! The new definition worked perfectly!   typename MapType::mapped_type& FindOrInitialize(GroupNumber_t Group, int SymbolRate, int FecRate, MapType Map)